# Cronjob problem executing php script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a hourly cronjob script that `curl`s a php script.  The php script isn't being executed.  In `crontab -e` I have:

`1      *       *       *       *        /var/www/path/to/script.sh`

Doing `grep cron /var/log/syslog` outputs:

```
Mar 23 21:45:01 Emile CRON[5339]: (root) CMD (/var/www/path/to/anotherscript.sh)
Mar 23 22:01:01 Emile CRON[5386]: (root) CMD (/var/www/path/to/anotherscript.sh)
Mar 23 22:01:01 Emile CRON[5387]: (root) CMD (/var/www/path/to/script.sh)
Mar 23 22:14:01 Emile CRON[5425]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar 23 22:15:01 Emile CRON[5429]: (root) CMD (/var/www/path/to/anotherscript.sh)
```

I've verified that the url that is being `curl` in `script.sh` is correct and that the path in `crontab -e` is correct.  I also verified that the php script works when manually executed.  What else is there?  Any ideas?  Another way to diagnose?  What's that `cd / && run-parts` in my syslog?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you checked your user's mail spool for error messages?  `run-parts` is used to run all the scripts placed in the `cron.hourly` and `cron.daily` (and weekly and monthly) directories.

Comment: When you say manually executed, do you mean "php /path/to/phpfile.php" or "curl http://url/to/phpfile.php"?  The first confirms that the .php file is valid and executable, the second will confirm if it can be gotten to via http, and if the web server will allow it to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What usually can happen is a `$PATH` problem. It's `curl` being used with it's full path on `script.sh` or just `curl`?

You can also change the first line of the script (if you are using bash) from `#!/bin/bash` to `#/bin/bash -x` (that will generate debug output from bash).

Anyway, as @derfK said on his comment, check the user email for errors (the script debug will also be sent to the user email). You can change the email which cron uses to send messages putting `MAILTO=<email>` before the rule lines.